# Delphi : how to check if a file exists (path over 255 characters)

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to make my delphi app able to check if a file copied using Robocopy is there or not when its path exceeds 255 characters.
I have tried the usual "If FileExists(MyFile) then ... " but it always returns "false" even if the file is there.

I also tried to get the file's date but I get 1899/12/30 which can be considered as an empty date.

A File search does not return anything either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prefix the file name with `\\?\` to enable extended-length path parsing. For example you would write

```
if FileExists('\\?\'+FileName) then
  ....
```

Note that this will only work if you are calling the Unicode versions of the Win32 API functions. So if you use a Unicode Delphi then this will do the job. Otherwise you'll have to roll your own version of `FileExists` that calls Unicode versions of the API functions.

These issues are discussed in great length over on MSDN: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#maxpath).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution works great with local paths such as e:\myfilepath but I remain stuck with UNC paths, even with "If FileExists('\\?\UNC\'+MyFile) then ..."

Comment: UNC paths work fine here. I'm pretty confident that my answer is all you need. Something else will be wrong. Once you have the `\\?\` prefix you have escaped the 260 limit.

Comment: @Fab: If `MyFile` contains a standard UNC path, you have to remove the leading `'\\'` from it when prepending the `'\\?\UNC\'` prefix. IOW, `'\\server\path'` needs to become `'\\?\UNC\server\path'`, not `'\\?\UNC\\\server\path'` like your code is currently doing.

Comment: What Remy says is accurate. Perhaps that's your problem. The article I link to says the same.

Comment: Remy is right, I forgot that point. I had to use "If copy(MyFile,0,2)='\\' then MyFile:=StringReplace(MyFile, '\\', '\\?\UNC\', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);" The FileExists works great then. Thanks !